# Using NDSolve on nonrectangular array

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have the following code and it works fine when my limits for for i&j are below. However, if i change my j limit to $\{$$j$,$0$,$\sqrt{kD^2-i^2}$,$\Delta k$$\}$ it doesn't work. Basically changing the limit to a semi-circle of radius kD. Any ideas so I don't have to figure out a way to rewrite all my code? The error I get is "NDSolve::ndinnt: Initial condition...is not a number or rectangular array...."

```
n = .825;
Λ = 50*2 π*n;
kD = Sqrt[2 Λ]; 
Δk = 0.4049530371583866`;
μ0 = 5.179757897064337`;
Δ0 = 5.05342819*10^-3;
xlamf = 0.0016448218708759214`;

(* Define Initial Conditions *)
    xy0 = Table[-((Sqrt[i^2 + j^2]*Δ0)/(
    2*Sqrt[((i^2 + j^2)/
        2 - μ0)^2 + (i^2 + j^2)*Δ0^2])), {i, -kD, 
    kD, Δk}, {j, 0, Sqrt[kD^2 - i^2], Δk}];
x0 = Re@xy0;
y0 = -Im@xy0;
z0 = Table[
   1/2*((2 μ0 - (i^2 + j^2))/(
     2*Sqrt[((i^2 + j^2)/
         2 - μ0)^2 + (i^2 + j^2)*Δ0^2])), {i, -kD, 
    kD, Δk}, {j, 0, Sqrt[
    kD^2 - i^2], Δk}];

deltarule = {delta[plus, x] :> -xlamf*(
     2 Δk^2)/π Total@Flatten@(Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2]*Sx),
            delta[plus, y] :> -xlamf*(
     2 Δk^2)/π Total@Flatten@(Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2]*Sy)};
(* Set up B *)
Bx = 2*Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2]*(delta[plus, x]);
By = 2*Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2]*(delta[plus, y]);
Bz = kx^2 + ky^2;

(* Calculate Equations of Motion *)
eom = {Bx, By, Bz}\[Cross]{Sx, Sy, Sz};

(* Let's create the list for the k's *)
krule = {kxlst -> 
    Table[i, {i, -kD, kD, Δk}, {j, 0, Sqrt[
      kD^2 - i^2], Δk}],
   kylst -> 
    Table[j, {i, -kD, kD, Δk}, {j, 0, Sqrt[
      kD^2 - i^2], Δk}]};

rhsfunc = (Hold@
         Compile[{{S, _Real, 3}},

          With[{kx = kxlst, ky = kylst}, 
           Module[{Sx, Sy, Sz}, {Sx, Sy, Sz} = S; #]], 
          CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True},
           RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False] /. 
        deltarule /. krule // ReleaseHold) &@eom;

(* Solve DE *)
tend = 100/Λ;
sol = NDSolveValue[{S'[t] == rhsfunc[S[t]], S[0] == {x0, y0, z0}}, 
    S, {t, 0, tend}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Your code works fine.  Please post the change that doesn't work for you and include the message name of the error you get (it's helpful).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the reply. The error I get it:
NDSolveValue::ndinnt: Initial condition {{{-0.000226483},{-0.000230757,-0.000230717,-0.000230599,-0.000230403,-0.000230128,-0.000229777,-0.00022935,-0.000228848,-0.000228273,-0.000227627,-0.000226911},<<48>>,<<63>>},{{0.},<<49>>,<<63>>},{{-0.5},<<49>>,<<63>>}} is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers.

The difference between the code I posted and the broken one is that all  j sums are changed to $\{ j,0,\sqrt{kD^2−i^2},\Delta k}$

Comment: I edited the original post to reflect the not working code.

Comment: @MichaelE2 sorry for the bump, but any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: No, not really.  My hunch is that it's not possible to get `NDSolve` to work with nonrectangular arrays, but I've left it for someone else to say definitively.  Perhaps you could "extend by zero" your problem on a semicircle to a rectangle?  (Usually you do it with `Piecewise` or some sort of discontinuous parameter that switches to something like `0` outside the region, so that what's outside the region integrates to zero and doesn't affect the interior. Maybe you can figure out if that's possible?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's a great idea and one that I think I can work with. Thank you for the help!